# toString method with for loop not working, not sure why

Tags: java

This is supposed to be a to string method that is the concatenation of all the items in this `ArrayList` but when I call it, it doesn't do anything at all.  I'm not getting any errors; it's just that the code does not do anything at all.

I had this working before, where it wasn't a for loop, it just called the `toString` method a bunch of times, but now that I'm trying to concatenate all the `toString` methods it doesn't work for some reason.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

    /*this class creates an object of type catalog used to put items into and defines
    methods used to manipulate this catalog object*/
    public class Catalog
    {
        // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
        private ArrayList<Item> items;
        private final int MAX = 20;
        private int size;
        private int itemNum;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class Catalog
         */
        public Catalog()
        {
            //makes empty arraylist
            // initialise instance variables
            items = new ArrayList<>(MAX);
            size = 0;

        }

        /**
         * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
         *
         * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
         * @return    the sum of x and y
         */
        public void addItem(Item theItem)
        {
            // put your code here
            items.add(theItem);
            size = items.size();


        }
        public Item remItem(int theItem)
        {
            Item temp = this.find(theItem);
            items.remove(temp);
            size = items.size();
            return temp;

        }

        public Item find(int itemNum){
            for (Item item : this.items){
               if (item.getItemNumber() == (itemNum)) {
                  return item;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String itemlist = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < this.items.size(); i++){
                itemlist += items.get(i).toString();
            }
            return itemlist;
        }

        public boolean isEmpty(){
            return items.isEmpty();
        }
    }
```

This is in another class:

```
  this.name = name;
        this.cat = new Catalog();
        //CREATE ARRAYLIST HERE
        cat.addItem(new Music(1111,"White and Nerdy",2.50,"\"Weird Al\" Yankovic"));



 else if((userChoice.equals("S")) || (userChoice.equals("s"))){
                   boolean empty = this.cat.isEmpty();
            if (empty == true){
                System.out.println("There is nothing in this catalog");
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
            else{
            this.cat.toString();
        }
```

This is my item class:

```
//This Is a class for a general Item 
public class Item
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int itemnum;
    private String title;
    private double price;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Item
     */
    public Item(int id, String t, double p)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        itemnum = id;
        title = t;
        price = p;
    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public int getItemNumber()
    {
        // put your code here
        return itemnum;
    }

    public String getItemType()
    {
        return "Item";
    }

    public String getItemTitle()
    {
      return title;  
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String line1, line2, line3, line4, out;
        String itemtype = this.getItemType();
        line1 = String.format("Item number: %d%n", itemnum);
        line2 = String.format("Item type: %s%n", itemtype);
        line3 = String.format("Item title: %s%n", title);
        line4 = String.format("Item price: %.2f%n", price);
        out = line1 + line2 + line3 + line4 + "\n";
        return out;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `items` list is not empty?

Comment: what is your `items` object ?

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the whole class, it would be a lot easier to help if you do.

Comment: No errors suggests the code is working. I imagine it has something to do with `this.items` not containing any data. Please post full code.

Comment: You are also concatenating inside of a loop, probably should use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: you are doing something funky in there. share the entire code block with all relevant objects.

Comment: Tip: Write a test and do some debugging. The code is NOT doing NOTHING, it is definitely running (as you would quickly find out if you debugged it - i.e. add some breakpoints)

Comment: Show us how you created the `Catalog` object, how did you use this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the test code with your Item class. Still no issues

```java
Catalog c = new Catalog();

System.out.println("Empty : " + c.toString());

c.addItem(new Item(1, "abc", 2d));
c.addItem(new Item(2, "def", 3d));
c.addItem(new Item(3, "ghi", 4d));

System.out.println("Not empty : " + c.toString());
```

Using the Item class you provided the output now is

Output :

```
Empty : 
Not empty : Item number: 1
Item type: Item
Item title: abc
Item price: 2.00

Item number: 2
Item type: Item
Item title: def
Item price: 3.00

Item number: 3
Item type: Item
Item title: ghi
Item price: 4.00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Try compiling your code and running it with the command line ( java -jar YourApp.jar ), but the IDE should also print it as it is in standard output.

Comment: im still not getting any output for this code.  maybe its an IDE error but I posted my item class just in case

Comment: @SteveRats I updated the example with the `Item` class you provided

Answer (score 0):

Probably this.items.size() is coming zero and it returns an empty string!